# Send request to Devices using Netty

Tags: java, netty

What's the best approach to  continuously and within a certain interval send request and get response to several IoT Devices using Netty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netty's IdleStateHandler schedules IdleStateEvents to be sent when a channel hasn't read or written data in a while. Should be a good starting point for you https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/timeout/IdleStateHandler.java

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll take a look at that.